# How to use CloudFront efficiently for less popular website?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

We are building a website which contains a lot of images and data. We have optimized a lot to make the website faster. Then we decided to use AWS CloudFront also to make it faster for all regions around the world. The app works faster after the integration of CloudFront.

But later we found that the data will load to CloudFront cache only when the website asks for it. So we are afraid that the initial load will take the same time as it used to take without the CDN because it loads from S3 to CDN first and then to the user.

Also, we used the default TTL values (ie., 24 hours). In our case, a user may log in once or twice per week to this website. So in that case also, the advantage of caching won't work here as well because the caching expires after 24 hours. Will raising the time of TTL (Maximum TTL) to a larger value solve the issue? Does it cost more money? And I also read that, increasing to a longer TTL is not a good idea as it has some disadvantages also for updating the data in s3.

Comment: Will all the users see the same content or will each user see a different content on the website?

Comment: Also, are there a lot of static content on the website? Like header or footer images or other media content that may be served to multiple users?

Comment: Most of the user will see the same contents. And the website contains a lot of static contents.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudfront will cache the response only after the first user requests for it. So it will be slow for the first user, but it will be significantly faster for every other user after the first user. So it does make sense to use Cloudfront.

Using the default TTL value is okay. Since most users will see the same content and the website has a lot of static components as well. Every user except the first user will see a fast response from your website. You could even reduce this to 10-12 hours depending on how often you expect your data to change.

There is no additional cost to increasing your TTL. However invalidation requests are charged. So if you want to remove a cache, there will be a cost added to it. So I would prefer to keep a short TTL as short as your data is expected to change, so you dont have to invalidate existing caches when your data changes. At the same time, maximum number of users can benefit from your CDN.

[No additional charge for the first 1,000 paths requested for invalidation each month. Thereafter, $0.005 per path requested for invalidation.](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/pricing/)

UPDATE: In the event that you only have 1 user using the website over a long period of time (1 week or so), it might not be of much benefit to use CloudFront at all. CloudFront and all caching services are only effective when there are multiple users requesting for the same resources.

However you might still have a marginal benefit using CloudFront, as the requests will be routed from the edge location to S3 over AWS's backbone network which is much faster than the internet. But whether this is cost effective for you or not depends on how many users are using the website and how slow it is.

Aside from using CloudFront, you could also try S3 Cross Region Replication to increase your overall speed. [Cross Region Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr.html) can replicate your buckets to a different region as and when they are added in one region. This can help to minimize latency for users from other regions.

Comment: If there is only one user using my website once a week from a particular region. In that case, the website will be always slow for him, right? If that's the case for all other regions, how can I address this situation? That's the ask.

Comment: Updated my answer, based on the inputs. Not sure if it helps :)

Comment: What if, I updated the Maximum TTL to 1 year and use invalidation or version identifier for file update? Is this a good approach or worse approach?

Comment: If you are okay with paying for the cost of invalidation, and your data doesn't change often. It would be a good approach In my opinion. By increasing TTL to 1 year, you are ensuring that CloudFront is able to effectively make it faster for most users (except the first user of course). And as and when your data changes, you can invalidate the cache.

Comment: But I would probably look for other ways to optimise the website and make the response faster instead of using CloudFront if the traffic is expected to be very less. But, you know your website and requirements best :)